# Apache Camel Split and Aggregate Looses Result of Aggregate Exchange

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to build a Split / Aggregate pattern in a Camel Route that consumes a REST endpoint. It takes a request object that contains a list of request details. I want to parallel process the request details and then return an aggregated result back to the caller. I want this to be a Synchronous call.

Here's the code in my Route.

```
from("{{generate.route.endpoint}}")
    .routeId(EXAMPLE_ROUTE_ID)
    .split().method(RequestDetailsSplitter.class).stopOnException().parallelProcessing()
        .to("direct:processRequestDetails")
        .aggregate(header(TRANSACTION_ID_PARAM), responseAggregator)
            .completionSize(simple("${property.CamelSplitSize}"))
            .completionTimeout(5000L).parallelProcessing()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "After Aggregation ---> ${body}")
     .end()            
    .removeHeaders("*")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 
               simple(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)));
```

I would expect that the result of the call is the output of Aggregate call, my response object. But what I actually get is the request object returned from the REST call??

When I put more logging statements in I can see that the Split call is firing multiple threads, which is great. And I can see the log statement above 'After Aggregation --->' with the response I want, this has it's own thread. But what happens to this output? How can I get that back into my default Exchange so it can returned to the REST call.

Answer (score 2):

From [Apache Camel: Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html):

> **What the Splitter returns**
>
> **Camel 2.3 and newer**:
>
> The Splitter will by default return the original input message.
>
> **For all versions**
>
> You can override this by suppling your own strategy as an **AggregationStrategy**.

If you want to aggregate the result of a split, you just need something like to:

```
from("{{generate.route.endpoint}}")
   .routeId(EXAMPLE_ROUTE_ID)
   .split().method(RequestDetailsSplitter.class, responseAggregator)
           .stopOnException().parallelProcessing()
           .to("direct:processRequestDetails")
           .end()            
   .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "After Split aggregate ---> ${body}")
   .removeHeaders("*")
   .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, simple(String.valueOf(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)));
```